# Why I am getting TCF Error 3.3 to my AdMob account?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting TCF Error 3.3

And as I found error 3.3 indicates that The TC string last updated date was more than 13 months ago. and the suggested action is CMP should delete the old TC string and reobtain consent.
And I am using funding choices as a CMP, so what is the status of the issue?
Do I need to do any changes to the app for it?

I am using below code to display EU Consent

```
func openEUConsent() {
        
        let parameters = UMPRequestParameters()
        parameters.tagForUnderAgeOfConsent = false
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(with: parameters,completionHandler: { [weak self] error in
                if error != nil{
                    nonFatalLog(title: requestConsentErrorTitle, description: error?.localizedDescription ?? "nil")
                }else{
                    let formStatus = UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.formStatus
                    switch formStatus {
                    case .available:
                        self?.loadForm()
                    case .unknown:
                        self?.openEUConsent()
                        print("Form Status unknown")
                        nonFatalLog(title: consentFormStatusUnknown, description: "nil")
                    case .unavailable:
                        self?.requestIDFA()
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

I am calling openEUConsent function every time in func viewWillAppear

Please guide me for this issue.

Thanks

I've used this same code in my other apps but there is no issue.